# Updating NULL Field vs Most Recent Record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which contains a null field. This needs to be populated from another table. While the statement for getting the information from the other table is simple I am concerned about performance of the update.

The update is done by a script scheduled to run every 30 minutes.

Which would be better:

- Update using a where field is null statement

  `UPDATE table1 
   SET freefield=(SELECT name FROM table2 WHERE table1.keyfield=table2.field) 
   WHERE freefield IS NULL;`
- Update using a statement that only updates the last X records

  `UPDATE table1 
   SET freefield=(SELECT name FROM table2 WHERE table1.keyfield=table2.field)
   WHERE ROWID IN
   (
      SELECT ROWID FROM 
      (
          SELECT keyfield
          FROM table1 
          ORDER BY keyfield DESC
      )
      WHERE ROWNUM < 300
   );`

table1.keyfield and table2.field are indexed and have primary/fk relation. table1.freefield and table2.name are not indexed and are text fields.

Currently the table is only about 100k record but will grow massively. Essentially I'm asking is it going to take longer for it to search for null fields in the table or for it to order it and use only the most recent number specified.

The final plan is to implement a trigger so records will be updated at creation properly but that cannot be implemented until the next release of our software for QC reasons etc.

Database is Oracle 10.2.0.5

The table itself has several indexes including the primary key (incremental number) which is what would be used to sort and update the most recent records.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table, or propose for each of your options?  They're going to be necessary if you want to avoid checking every single row every single time *(a table scan)* and instead just parse a specific section of the table *(an index seek or index range-seek)*.  Oh, and which RDBMS are you using?  MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, PostGreSQL, etc, etc?

Comment: Updated to include RDBMS and index details

Comment: Please give actual details on the indexes (which fields), and the queries you propose to use for the UPDATE.

Comment: Updated to include index details and the actual update statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function-based index to only identify the rows with NULL.
Such an index will be very small.

```
create index index_name 
    on owner.table_name(case when your_column is null then 'x' end) compress 1;
```

To update the column you would do:

```
update owner.table_name
   set your_column = <your-logic-here>
 where (case when your_column is null then 'x' end) = 'x';
```

**Edit after initial question was changed:**
Your two options doesn't give the same result. Only option 1 would implement the requirement to "update all missing missing `freefield`".

If you get more than 300 inserts per 30 minutes, not all of them will be updated with option 2. Also, you have introduced an unnecessary dependency that may or may not hold true in the future: That whenever record R1.keyfield > record R2.keyfield, then record R1 is newer than R2.

Comment: Thank you, for my scenario this may actually be the best solution given the constraints I have i.e unable to change the application accessing the data etc.

Comment: I will probably use this solution but for the sake of completeness are you able to answer the initial question as to which was better out of the two options I put forward?

Comment: "If you get more than 300 inserts per 30 minutes, not all of them will be updated with option 2." I accept what you saying is correct but for my scenario we can assume that there will never be more than 300 inserts in 30 minutes so that would not be an issue here.

Comment: "Also, you have introduced an unnecessary dependency that may or may not hold true in the future: That whenever record R1.keyfield > record R2.keyfield, then record R1 is newer than R2." - I think I understand what you mean here and in my scenario it is safe to assume the key for new records will always be the highest.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to do the first, update where the field is `NULL`.  The intention seems to be keep the table so the only `NULL` values are the most recent values.  I'm a strong advocate of writing code that does what you intend.

If you only attempt to update the last XX records, then you have conditions where you might miss some of the `NULL` values:

- More records are inserted in the time period than you expect.
- You miss one or more update periods for some reason.

If you are concerned about performance, then add an index on the field to facilitate finding the records you want.

Finally, if the update is simple, then you might consider just using a view and doing all access through the view:

```
create view v_table as
    select coalesce(col, 0) as ReplaceTheNull
    from table;
```

This approach would obviate the need for updates.

Comment: Unfortunately updates would be needed as there is an application which access the data and would require development changes to access a view. Am I naive in thinking you could run an update on everything that was in the view though?

Comment: @Zammalad . . . You might be able to name the table something like `_table` and then name the view `table` and most other code should then work.

Comment: thanks, that would probably work but again it would need my HQ to sign off on it and I doubt they would. Thanks for the suggestion though